# Is it possible for apps to interfere with multi-touch system wide?

Tags: multi-touch

I'm having multi-touch issues with Swype. However, other users with same phone are reporting A-OK, so I'm wondering if PEBKAC or ID-10-T. However, I have tested bone stock after a factory reset and experienced the same behavior.

Comment: I think you should reduce the scope to answering by mentioning what User/system apps you have installed in your device. Think about it, there can be many apps responsible for the issue but not useful as an answer to you in case you don't have them installed. Only an opinion here. :)

Comment: Yeah I apologize for the spammy question. Perhaps I should rephrase if it's hypothetically possible for an app to interfere, and if so how would it do it.